# Update datetimefiled of all related models when model is updated

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models (Post and Display). Both have Datetime-auto fields. My problem is that i want to update all display objects related to a post, once a post is updated.

I have read here that you could override one models save method, but all the examples are About updating the model with the foreign key in it and then call the save method of the other model. In my case it's the other way arround. How can i do this ?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Room, related_name='roomposts',  through='Display')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/post/{}/".format(self.pk)

class Display(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isdisplayed = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.isdisplayed)
```

i want to update the date_posted of all related Display-objects once their related post is changed. I do not know if overriding the save-method works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case you should have a look at django's reverse foreign key documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

in your case you can override the save method on your Post model

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    #either: this excutes many sql statments
    for display in self.display_set.all():
        display.save()
    #or faster: this excute only one sql statements,
    #but note that this does not call Display.save
    self.display_set.all().update(date_posted=self.date_posted)
```

The name `display_set` can be changed using the `related_name` option

in Display, you can change it:

`post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='displays')`

Then, instead of using `self.display_set` in your code, you can use `self.displays`

Comment: also, like the other answer suggested, you can do it in the `post_save` signal

Answer (score 1):

Overriding save method works, but that's not were you should go, imo.

What you need is signals:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def update_displays_on_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created') is False:  # This means you have updated the post
        # do smth with instance.display_set
```

Usually it goes into `signals.py`.
Also you need to include this in you AppConfig

```
def ready(self):
    from . import signals  # noqa
```